# Building a partial state inside an action to update a REST API

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

I have a bound action:

```
updateAge(age)
```

Part of my state is this:

```
//user data
user {
   name: 'foo',
   age: 10
}
```

In my action creator, can I do something like this?

```
export const updateAge = (age) => (dispatch, getState) => { 
   let currentState = { ...getState().user, age }
   dispatch(updateUser(currentState)) //updates API
}
```

This would save work on my back end as I would just have one route handling all user updates.

```
router.post('/user'....)
```

As long as I make sure only one fetch/post happens at any given time, is this a good pattern?  What are the pros and cons?

Comment: Hey there, can you explain why it requires that only one/fetch/post happens at a time? I use `redux-saga` mostly so queuing up effects are handled nicely. But I'd imagine that the thunks would just fire all the api calls one by one and the back end would deal with them whenever the next tic is available. Are you concerned about race conditions?

Comment: Right, normally I wouldn't worry about this but since I'm building a partial state before posting to the API, I think there would be situations where I'm sending the API an outdated piece of state, and overwriting it.  If this were just incremental, one step (not sure if there's a better word to describe this) changes, I wouldn't worry about this.   


For example, in this case if a user updates his age and name, the second call would overwrite the first call if it fires before the state is updated from the first call.

Comment: I guess my question should be: can I send state to my API or is the pattern to only send the change?

Comment: I still use Rails and one recent-ish upgrade promoted the use of PATCH to PUT. The rails team naturally provided reasoning: patch is sending the changed pieces, and put is to replace the whole thing. So the fact that there are these two HTTP verbs coexisting, the much brighter minds behind them must have considered both scenarios and thought them have own merits. But maybe a PATCH is safer for your case then?